# Open source Android SMS app that can mute messages from specific contacts

Tags: android, open-source, notification, sms

I am looking for an open source SMS app for Android that can mute the contacts that I specify. I want to avoid being shown notifications when I receive SMS from particular contacts. However, I still want to be able to read the SMS from a muted contact when I open the SMS app. The app should run on Android 8.1 or later.

Answer (score 0):

[QKSMS](https://github.com/moezbhatti/qksms) can do this. It is available via the [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.moez.QKSMS) and [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.moez.QKSMS/). QKSMS is able to disable notifications for someone with whom you have sent or received at least one message. To disable notifications from a particular person, view the messages from that person and tap on "kebab menu" (three vertical dots), where you will have an option to customize notifications for that particular person.